# Pretty urls (friendly_id gem) with dots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url

Many solutions are available for rails 2 but none for rails 3.1 because the map object has been removed.

Any solution for this problem in the latest rails?

Comment: I don't understand what "with dots" means.

Comment: dots as in . THe dot you use at the end of a sentence. :)

Comment: Example www.myurl.com/m.y.c.o.m.p.a.n.y

Answer (score 2):

I have had to do this recently on a project. Luckily, it's simple to override the slug-generating method on a per-model basis.

please refer to

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb#L113-116

and

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb#L227-231

you should be able to define this on the model:

```
# Use default slug, but upper case and with underscores
def normalize_friendly_id(string)
  super.upcase.gsub("-", ".")
end
```

Hope this helps.

Note: This method is available in FriendlyId 3.x as well. It's great for defining a custom regex for generating slug strings.